# Unique Index on partition table isse

Tags: postgresql

How we can eliminate duplicate insertion after postgres partitions.

As Partition key on unique constraint causing non key attribute duplicate.

EX: ID date

```
 1 1-01-2022

 1 02-01-2022
```

To make ID unique we have  before insert trigger is the only option, Any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a unique constraint on a partitioned table that does not contain the partitioning key. A trigger won't be a reliable solution either, because it would be subject to race conditions (concurrent inserts) unless you are running with the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

The best you can have is unique constraints on each individual partitions.

The best you can do is fill the values from a sequence, so that the values are automatically unique, for example with an identity column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have implemented this partition level constraint but table level I see few duplicates.

Comment: The database cannot prevent that.